what is the time complexity of this code:
int c = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < n; i += i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        c++;
    }
}

I attempted to analyze the time complexity by considering how many times each loop runs. I know that the outer loop runs as long as i is less than n, and i doubles each time. The inner loop runs from 0 to i-1 for each iteration of the outer loop.
I expected to determine the overall time complexity of the code. Initially, I thought the complexity might be O(n log n) because the outer loop runs log(n) times due to the doubling of i, and the inner loop runs i times for each i.
I'm confused about how to sum the total number of operations for the inner loop across all iterations of the outer loop. I understand it forms a geometric series, but I'm not sure how that translates to the overall time complexity.
Could someone help me understand the correct time complexity and the reasoning behind it?

This is intentionally tricky: note "i += i" in the outer loop.
Let us try it on a reasonably large number. Say, n = 100.

First iteration: i = 1; the inner statement is executed 1 time.
Second iteration: i = 2; the inner statement is executed 2 times.
Third iteration: i = 4; the inner statement is executed 4 times.
Fourth iteration: i = 8; the inner statement is executed 8 times.
Fifth iteration: i = 16; the inner statement is executed 16 times.
Sixth iteration: i = 32; the inner statement is executed 32 times.
Seventh iteration: i = 64; the inner statement is executed 64 times.
Then i = 128 and we stop.

The total number of "c++" in the inner statement is therefore:
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 + 32 + 64 = 127.
Now, 127 looks similar enough to 100.
So the correct answer might be "linear", O(n).
If so, how do we prove it?
First, let us formulate what is the above sum.
It is the sum of all powers of two which are less than n.
Indeed, the variable "i" is doubled in each iteration, until it is less than "n", and the number of inner loop iterations is then just equal to "i".
Now, how do we estimate the sum?
As it is a geometric series, we have a formula for that: the sum is (2^{k+1} - 1) / (2 - 1) where 2^k is the largest power of two which is less than n.
The denominator is 1. So the sum is just 2^k, doubled, minus one.
Now, 2^k, in turn, is between n and n/2, because it is the largest such power. In the end, we have:

a number between n and and n/2,
doubled,
minus one.

This is now clearly O(n) (Theta(n) to be exact, since it's bounded from above and below).

According to me the time complexity is approximately O(n) and the space complexity is O(1) Because:
The outer loop runs log(n) times because the loop variable i doubles in each iteration until it reaches n. The inner loop runs i times in each iteration of the outer loop. Therefore, the total number of iterations of the inner loop is n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + ... + 1, which is equal to n - 1.
Since the inner loop increments the counter c by 1 in each iteration, the total number of operations is n - 1, making the time complexity O(n).
The space complexity is O(1) because the amount of memory used by the program does not increase with the input size n.
BUT IF YOU CONSIDER SIZE OF N=5 (ASSUME) THEN FOR THE LAST CASE WHEN I =5 THEN J WILL RUN AT LEAST 4 TIMES WHICH IS AROUND O(N)^2
SO ACCORDING TO ME IT SHOULD BE O(n)log(n).

I would prefer if you didn't use ALL CAPS in your answer. All caps in online communication are commonly interpreted as yelling.
